# How to use the cl_khr_3d_image_writes extension to OpenCL in macOS Big Sur

Tags: macos, opencl

Currently, I'm trying to enable the cl_khr_3d_image_writes extension for OpenCL on my M1 Mac however the cl_kernel.h file is read-only and can't be written to. I've disabled SIP however the problem persists. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: [The use of OpenCL is deprecated since macOS 10.14 (Mojave)](https://appleinsider.com/articles/18/06/04/opengl-opencl-deprecated-in-favor-of-metal-2-in-macos-1014-mojave) -  since OpenCL needs drivers to support it, you're out of luck. And even if you could modify the *.h file, you'd not be able to get that feature unless you patch it yourself.

Comment: Try`sudo vim cl_kernel.h`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me what editing the header file would achieve. Editing system headers is almost always a bad idea, and when you find yourself wanting to do that, it's usually a good idea to take a step back and think about what you *really* are trying to achieve. There's almost always a better way than editing a system header.

So, you want to use 3D image writes.

- Does your device report support for this extension? This is the first thing to check, and you should always check this on the end user's system too before trying to use an extension or you'll have more difficult error handling to deal with down the line.
- macOS supports OpenCL 1.2, [which has direct support for the 3D image write functions](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/write_image3d.html). When creating your context, make sure you create a version 1.2 compatible context, not version 1.0/1.1.
- In OpenCL 1.2, all you should need to do if the device supports the extension, is to enable it and call those built-in functions to perform the writes.
- To enable use of the extension in your kernel, use `#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_3d_image_writes : enable`

I should point out that OpenCL is deprecated on macOS, and it is being replaced by Metal compute shaders. When developing new software, it's recommended that you use those instead.

Comment: The device does support the use of the extension. Unfortunately, the library I'm using requires cl_khr_3d_image_writes to function. Seems I'll have to edit the library source.